# How to retrieve the call stack after an exception is raised in Python?

Tags: python, exception, inspect

In the example below, I would like to know which class and which function returned an error. I played with `traceback` but I don't get anything relevant `(None, None, None)`, `[]`, ...

import builtins

```
class AssertionError(BaseException):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
        print(sys.exc_info())
        tb = sys.exc_info()[-1]
        stk = traceback.extract_tb(tb, 1)
        print(stk)
        # for func_name in functions_chain:
        #     if func_name.starts_with('test'):
        #         get_function(func_name)._status = 'failure'

        raise builtins.AssertionError

class Foo:
    def run(self):
        self.test()

    def test(self):    
        assert False

Foo().run()
```

I would like to get the name of the functions called before the assertion error. Here I should get `['test', 'run']`. If I find a function name starting with `test`, I would like to tag it with an attribute that I can later read from the `Foo` instance.

How can I catch what I need in the `AssertionError` ?

Currently I get this output:

```
() {}
NoneType: None
(None, None, None)
[]
```

Comment: Python's stack trace system is really weird - it builds stack traces as an exception propagates, rather than at exception construction or at the initial `raise`. Even once a stack trace is "complete", it may look nothing like what the stack looked like when the exception occurred.

Comment: Are you trying to change how `assert` works? Naming a class `AssertionError` won't do that. You can't replace the built-in `AssertionError`. Even screwing with the `builtins` module won't do it.

Comment: I think pytest does that, isn't?

Comment: pytest actually rewrites your code to change the `assert` statements into something else. It doesn't try to mess with `AssertionError`.

Comment: (Messing with `AssertionError` wouldn't actually be enough to achieve what pytest does, anyway.)